# Text overlay not working in certain browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

I have successfully create the code needed to have an image and then a child element with text and overlay the text over the image. However it doesn't seem to work on `IE` and I cant find the work around using CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row background-lightgrey p-0 m-0 pt-4">
  <div class="col-md-6 m-0 p-0">
    <h2 class="m-4 color-orange font-weight-light">Canvas Ultipro</h2>
    <div class="ican-ultiproImage m-4">
      <img class="w-100" src="assets/images/ultipro.png" height="500" />
    </div>
    <div class="ican-ultiproImageText p-2 pl-5 m-4">
      <div class="row p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col ican-ultipProImageOverlay">
          <h2 class="ican-ultipProImageTitle">
            Canvas UltiPro
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 m-0 p-0">
    <h2 class="m-4 color-orange font-weight-light">Canvas Accord</h2>
    <div class="ican-ultiproImage m-4">
      <img class="w-100" src="assets/images/ultipro.png" height="500" />
    </div>
    <div class="ican-ultiproImageText p-2 pl-5 m-4">
      <div class="row p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col ican-ultipProImageOverlay">
          <h2 class="ican-ultipProImageTitle">
            Canvas UltiPro
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .ican-ultiproImage {
    height: 500px;
 }

.ican-ultiproImageText {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(107,107,107,0.6);
}
```

I have to use pure CSS and im also using bootstrap. I cant seem to understand whats going on in IE to cause such a dramatic shift. Setting the width of `ican-ultiproImageText` to `auto` or `inherited` doesnt make a difference.

**VIEW ON CHROME**
[image: View on chrome]

**VIEW ON IE**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add left: 0; to the css like

```
.ican-ultiproImageText {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(107,107,107,0.6);
}
```

Then it should work.